# Remove rel="attachment wp-att-XX"

Tags: images

When you add an image with "Add media" to the WYSIWYG editor the link around the image automatically gets a rel="attachment wp-att-XX". I would like to remove this with a script - Can anyone help me? :)

Comment: Why do you want this removed? It's useful information TinyMCE may be using, that has no impact on the frontend..

Comment: Because the site will not validate if it is printed :)
the solution posted by Max Yudin is perfect - because it allows TinyMCE to still use the info

Comment: That seems like an awful waste of time and money, I hope you've been charging your client for the faffery around this non-essential change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it right before post is printed to the screen by stripping it out from content. But remember it still will meddle in Editor.

```
<?php
function my_remove_rel_attr($content) {
    return preg_replace('/\s+rel="attachment wp-att-[0-9]+"/i', '', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_remove_rel_attr');
```

Comment: See birgire's answer for better `add_filter()`.

Comment: you version did the trick :)
Could this code be modified to remove the whole link?

Comment: You need different pattern for `preg_replace()`. But I'm not a guru in regular expressions. Also it's off-topic here.

Comment: Here you are:`$pattern = '{(<a\s[^>]+>).?(<img\s[^>]+>).?(</a>)+}Ui';
    $output = preg_replace($pattern, '$2', $image_inside_link);
`

Comment: Take care of attributes, they are in different order sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you mean instead of this html:

```
<a href="http://example.com/?attachment_id=1375" rel="attachment wp-att-1375"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image-300x78.jpg" alt="image.jpg" width="300" height="78" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-1375" /></a>
```

you want:

```
<a href="http://example.com/?attachment_id=1375" ><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image-300x78.jpg" alt="image.jpg" width="300" height="78" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-1375" /></a>
```

in your editor when you press "*Insert into post*".

Then you can try to use the filter `image_send_to_editor` and replace the `rel`-part of the html that is inserted into the editor:

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'wpse_88984_remove_rel', 10, 2);
function wpse_88984_remove_rel($html, $id) {
    if($id>0)
        $html=str_replace('rel="attachment wp-att-'.$id.'"','',$html);

    return $html;   
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's better to hook to `image_send_to_editor`. But I still prefer `preg_replace` against messing with `$id`.

Comment: yes I agree with the preg_replace, maybe he should use the mix of both answers ;-)

Comment: would not do it as the editor might use that information at some point. Max's answer is probably safer

Comment: yeah, I would most likely leave the attribute alone altogether, if I was looking into this today :-)