# Link post images to post

Tags: posts, images, permalinks

For some reason I can not find any good solution to making the post images link to the post.

I found a script on http://wpguy.com/plugins/linked-image/ which works - but does not remove the old link, instead it wraps the old link and the image in a new a tag.

What I want is for the old link to be removed so the image is only wrapped in one a tag.

This is the script I currently have:

```
function wpguy_linked_image($content){

    $searchfor = '/(<img[^>]*\/>)/';
    $replacewith = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">$1</a>';

    if (is_single() === FALSE){
        $content = preg_replace($searchfor, $replacewith, $content, 1);
    }
    return $content;

}

add_filter('the_content', 'wpguy_linked_image');
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It's not about WordPress, it's about regexes.

Comment: @MaxYudin This **is** about WordPress. What tool one uses to solve a WordPress problem doesn’t matter: HTTP, JavaScript, PHP or regular expressions.

Comment: @toscho I disagree. Original Poster already got the [answer here:](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88984/remove-rel-attachment-wp-att-xx). This is not a place to fight. But I don't see regexes as part of WordPress. It's PERL legacy and so on.

Comment: @MaxYudin As you can see by the answer this might be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), the regex might not even be needed.

Comment: Yes, @toscho. I agree, but how can we avoid XY? Nobody is reading FAQ, which is not full and is under construction for months.

Comment: @MaxYudin With patience. :) When in doubt try to help _here_.

Comment: @toscho have a nice `array('night' => 'Europe', 'day' => 'USA or near')`. I'm falling asleep.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, don't use regex for parsing HTML but use DOM instead.

This is how I would work it out :

In your toolbox, a function to get innerDOM of a node :

```
// GET INNER HTML OF A NODE
function DOMinnerHTML($element)  
{ 
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children = $element->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
        $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
        $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
    } 
    return $innerHTML; 
}
```

Then a filter to apply a custom function :

```
function change_destination_links_for_images( $content ) {   
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    // THIS IS HACK TO LOAD STRING WITH CORRECT ENCODING
    // JUST OUTPUT <--?xml encoding="UTF-8"--> IN HTML SO NO HARM
    $dom->loadHTML( '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' .  $content );

    // GET ALL <a> NODE
    foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node ) {
        // GET HREF 
        $link_href = $node->getAttribute( 'href' );
        // USE INNER OF THIS <a> NODE AS NEW DOC TO EXTRACT IMG
        $dom_node = new DOMDocument();
        $inner = DOMinnerHTML($node);
        $dom_node->loadHTML($inner);
        // CHECK IF IMAGE INSIDE THE LINK
        if ( $dom_node->getElementsByTagName('img') {
           // IF SO REPLACE HREF
           $node->setAttribute('href', get_permalink() );
           // RETURN MODIFIED DOM
           $content = $dom->saveHTML();
        }
    }
// RETURN CONTENT
return $content;
}
// APPLY FILTER
add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_destination_links_for_images' );
```

This is a quick adaptation of a working job I have done for another purpose so it may have errors in it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a soloution, I combined the script with a script which removes the orginal image links:

```
/**
 * Remove links from images
  */
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );
function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
    $content =
        preg_replace(array('{<a[^>]*><img}','{/></a>}'), array('<img','/>'), $content);
    return $content;
}


/**
 * Link images to post
 */
function wpguy_linked_image($content){

    $searchfor = '/(<img[^>]*\/>)/';
    $replacewith = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">$1</a>';

    if (is_single() === FALSE){
        $content = preg_replace($searchfor, $replacewith, $content, 1);
    }
    return $content;

}

add_filter('the_content', 'wpguy_linked_image');
```